# Deleting words from an NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring

I'm trying to remove a string from an NSString.

I have the Device Name

```
NSString * deviceName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];
```

and I'm trying to remove the 's iPhone 's iPod & 's iPad. How do I go about this? I've tried `stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString` but that didn't work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
NSString *deviceName = @"Kenny's iPhone";
NSString *stripped = [deviceName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'s iPhone" withString:@""];
```

The stripped variable has the string @"Kenny" after that line. Remember that -stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: doesn't alter your existing string, it returns a new string with the changes.

Comment: Wow! that was so simple! Don't know how I missed it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Magician Software: If it solved your problem, accept the answer! And then go to your old questions and accept the answers there too.